# How to limit the width and height of a java game?

Tags: java, jpanel

I'm building a click game. You need to click the rat that appears on the screen, if you clicked it, you get 1 point for every 'hit' on a rat.

My gamescreen looks like this:
[image: catch game]

The whole image is set as a background. Now I want to limit the actual game field to only use the wooden floor.

How can I do this? I'm fairly new to Java, so I don't know how it's called.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Cursor;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Gamevenster extends JPanel implements Runnable {
        public String Gamestatus = "active";
        private Thread thread;
        //public Main game;

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(achtergrond, 0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(), null);
        g.drawImage(muisje, 10, 10, null);
    }

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        Image achtergrond, muisje;
        JTextField invoer;
        JButton raden;
        JButton menu;

        Gamevenster() {
        setLayout(null);

        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("assets/achtergrondspel.png"));
        achtergrond = icon.getImage();      

        ImageIcon icon2 = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("assets/muisje.png"));
        muisje = icon2.getImage();   

        //Get the default toolkit  
        Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();  

        //Load an image for the cursor  
        Image image = toolkit.getImage("src/assets/hand.png");  

        //Create the hotspot for the cursor  
        Point hotSpot = new Point(0,0);

        //Create the custom cursor  
        Cursor cursor = toolkit.createCustomCursor(image, hotSpot, "Hand");

        //Use the custom cursor  
        setCursor(cursor);

        // setLayout( null );

        // Invoer feld
        invoer = new JTextField(10);
        invoer.setLayout(null);
        invoer.setBounds(150, 474, 290, 60); // Verander positie onder aan scherm is int 1

        // Button voor raden
        raden = new JButton("Raden");
        raden.setLayout(null);
        raden.setBounds(10, 474, 130, 60);
        raden.setFont(new Font("Dialog", 1, 20));
        raden.setForeground(Color.white);
        raden.setBackground(new Color(46, 204, 113));
        raden.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(130, 60));

        // Menu knop
        menu = new JButton("Menu");
        menu.setLayout(null);
        menu.setBounds(450, 474, 130, 60);
        menu.setFont(new Font("Dialog", 1, 20));
        menu.setForeground(Color.white);
        menu.setBackground(new Color(46, 204, 113));
        menu.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(130, 60));

        // Toevoegen aan screen
        add(invoer);
        //add(raden);
        add(menu);

        menu.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

enter code herepublic void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String i = invoer.getText();
        System.out.println("Er is gedrukt! " + i);
                }
            });
        }

        public void start(){
            thread = new Thread(this,"spelloop");
            thread.start();
        }

        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            while(Gamestatus=="active"){
                System.out.println("Gameloop werkt");
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use JPanel ,and set background on that.
Then you can use the onClickListener on the panel 
and work your way through the game.

You can also set mouse motion listener to limit the 
area you have covered for the wooden floor under the 
JPanel.

Comment: The whole screen you see in the screenshot is a JPanel, can I add another JPanel in there? is it that easy?

Comment: Use JFrame as the opening screen, as it is the standard way of doing it.
Then you can embed a JPanel inside a JFrame.
Or else if you wish for a JPanel, then include a JPanel inside a Jpanel also.

Comment: I added my piece of code for the game screen. Hope it makes it easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Create `JLabel` named `img` and set an image icon to it.

Set `layout` of  the `frame` as `BorderLayout` .

Add the label `img` to the frame.

Add components(your `Panel`) to the label `img` instead of the frame.

Layout for the `img`label is set as `FlowLayout`.

[This](http://java-demos.blogspot.in/2012/09/setting-background-image-in-jframe.html) link will help you

Comment: Don't add image on the `Panel`. Go to the `JFrame` on which you are adding this `Panel` and follow the steps which I have mentioned in the answer.

Comment: I make use of a CardLayout, so the game starts at a welcome screen, but a start and quit button, when I click the start button it goes to the screen you see on the image. So I think I can't add the background to the JFrame.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: @KeesSonnema Example has been mentioned in the link given in above answer. Check the last line of the answer. If you want `CardLayout` then add your `Panel`  `Gamevenster` to the `img` label (which I have mentioned in answer) and set The Layout of `img` label as `CardLayout`.

Comment: I think I came up with an better idea. Just draw the mouse/rat to somewhere around the half of the screen, in this way the mouse/rat never goes outside the 'wood'